# How to load only a certain type of image (functions.php)

Tags: images, filters

Can only images of a certain type be loaded from the media library in the customization panel? eg: png. I tried some types but it didn't work.

```
 $wp_customize->add_setting( 'themeslug_logo', array(

       'default'           => '',) );

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
    $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Logo', 'themeslug' ),
        'section'    => 'sluzby_section',
        'settings'   => 'themeslug_logo',
        'extensions' => array( 'ico', 'png' ), // Still loading all images
        // 'I found another one but that didn't work either'
    )));
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JavaScript to add a quick validation that checks the file type when someone tries to add an image. Place this script in your theme's main JS file or inline in your `functions.php`.

Here's a snippet of JavaScript to give you an idea:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    wp.customize.control('themeslug_logo', function(control) {
        control.uploader.params.allowed_extensions = ['png'];
        control.container.on('click keydown', '.upload-button', function() {
            control.uploader.uploader.plupload.uploader.settings.filters.mime_types = [{title: 'Allowed Files', extensions: 'png'}];
        });
    });
});
```

This will limit the media uploader to only show **PNG** files when someone tries to upload an image for your logo setting in the Customizer.

Give that a shot and let us know how it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but javascript is not exactly my friend. I added the code to the functions.php file and ran the template. After clicking the button (themeslug_logo) - "Choose image" the media library opens and just spins loading. Nothing will show up. The same thing happens when you open the main media library.I apologize for my English.

Comment: @JosefVolný you can't place a JS code directly in your functions.php file. It would not work obviously. You need to add that JS code I share inline through your functions.php. That means you need to use some custom action that will spit out the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If I understand it correctly, you need to wrap the code in one more function. So I tried this but it still spins loading. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your patience.

```
function my_inline_script() 
{ echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        wp.customize.control('themeslug_logo1', function(control) {
            control.uploader.params.allowed_extensions = ['png'];
            control.container.on('click keydown', '.upload-button', function() {
                control.uploader.uploader.plupload.uploader.settings.filters.mime_types = [{
                    title: 'Allowed Files',
                    extensions: 'png'
                }];
            });
        });
    });
</script>
"; 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_inline_script');
```

I also tried this code, but it also spins when loading.

```
function my_inline_script() {
    wp_register_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Files.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
    }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_inline_script' );
```